# SQL Server Installation issue

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, installation

I have a question relating to SQL Server management studio,

I have downloaded the SQL Server Express onto my PC and was told to expect SQL Server  to prompt me for a username and password, which I could use to login  as "SQL Server Authentication", and use the login and password function.

I followed every single instance of the Installation but was never propted about any such password and user name setting having to be created.

Big deal however I need to practice methods for loging into SQL Server using password and Username functionality ussing vb.net (Automating login procedures).

What are the steps I need to undertake to make correct this?

Comment: If during the install, you did not choose "Mixed Mode" security, it will default to NT Auth which does not allow a user name and password.  Make sure you choose mixed mode, then you will get the prompt.

Comment: When you were installing sql server it must have asked you what authentication mode you want to select. It gives you two option there 1) Mix mode 2) Windows Authentication which one did you select ??

Comment: No it didnt ask anything beyond the point where it said "Are you sure you want to install SQL Server" (Generic microsoft warning).

Answer (score 1):

The Authentication Mode can be changed at any time.  In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, right-click on your server, and go to properties.

In the Security page, you have the option to change the Server Authentication mode to Windows or Both (Windows and SQL).

Make sure the "*sa*" user has a strong password (it may be empty or disabled by default).